# fopen works in main but not in a function in another file

Tags: c, fopen, permission-denied, errno

I'm trying to open a .bdf font file using fopen. This works fine when called in main() however when I try and load the font in a function that is in another file, I get a Permission Denied message, with the error # of 13 from errno.

I'm compiling this using a makefile and running this on a raspberry pi with:

```
./sudo clock
```

These are the two files

main.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "clock.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char *path = "/home/pi/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/clock/fonts/6x12.bdf";
  FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");
  if (f == NULL) {
    perror(path);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed load %d <-- Main\n", errno);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Font load succeeded <-- Main\n");
  }
  
  // Set up Clock Face
  initialiseClockFace();

  return 0;
}
```

clock.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

void initialiseClockFace();
```

clock.cc

```
#include "clock.h"

void initialiseClockFace() {
  const char *path = "/home/pi/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/clock/fonts/6x12.bdf";
  FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");
  if (f == NULL) {
    perror(path);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed load %d <-- Clock\n", errno);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Font load succeeded <-- Clock\n");
  }

}
```

When running, it prints the following:

```
Font load succeeded <-- Main
/home/pi/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/clock/fonts/6x12.bdf: Permission denied
Failed load 13 <-- Clock
```

Looking at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html,
unless I'm mistaken the error number 13 is:

```
 [EROFS]
 The named file resides on a read-only file system and mode requires write access.
```

I've tried searching for my problem on stackoverflow and Google but can't seem to find any answers. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems likely that the first `fopen` has locked the file, so the second `fopen` fails. Since you are not using either file handle it's hard to be sure what to suggest as an alternative. You could try closing the file in `main` with `fclose` before you call `initializeClockFace`, or you could pass the file handle from main to `initializeClockFace` instead of trying to open it again.

Comment: Your are mistaken, error 13 does not mean the 13th error listed on that page. That's not how `errno` works. You need to check your header files to determine which of the ***error names*** listed on that page are defined ***on your*** system as error 13.

Comment: Assuming that your Raspberry runs a Linux variant, error number 13 is most likely `EACCES`. This is also hinted at by the `perror` message, "Permission denied".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the file is locked because of the fopen call in main.
In general I would suggest to avoid C-functions. You should use std::fstream because it releases your handle automatically.

Check if it works with a fclose-call before initialiseClockFace.

Comment: Good advice but in this case the file would not be released until after the `initializeClockFace` function has been called.

Comment: I originally had the fopen call in the initiateClockFace function only but copied it across to the main to see if it would work there. I got the same failure messages when the fopen call wasn't in the main function.  I'll try using fstream and see if that works.

Comment: @user794895 I think you cannot have reproduced your code correctly. Look at your error message `the mode requires write access`, but in the code above you are clearly asking for read access `"r"`, so that doesn't make sense. Moving an `fopen` call from one function to another should not stop it working (if that's the only change).

Comment: Whether one uses fopen or fstream, that will have absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with the error in question, assuming that everything else is identical.

Comment: fstream also fails to load, so that didn't solve the problem.

@john I copy/pasted the code, so it's definitely what I've got in my program.

Comment: @user794895 errno 13 means (aparently) permission denied so it seems you do not have permission to read that file. you confused me by quoting the other error message, but as Sam pointed out that is not correct.

Comment: Shouldn't it be fine to call ```fopen``` twice on the same file? It would just open two descriptors. Makes me think this issue is something else than just the call location.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem, I was calling another function in a class that wasn't closing it's fopen properly.

Thanks for taking the time to help.